# AVFrame deprecated attributes to regain?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I want to print out some attributes of video frames: I've looked into AVFrame struct, but only found the following disappointments:

```
attribute_deprecated short *    dct_coeff
attribute_deprecated uint32_t *     mb_type
```

It seems to me everything I am interested in is already obsolete. Btw, I didn't find

```
int16_t(*[2]    motion_val )[2]
```

attribute in the actual frame I captured. My question is: how can i get access to those attributes such as dct_coeff or motion_vector or mb_type of a frame at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`av_frame_get_side_data`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#gadec0efb470b1eead6a979333d9deca0c)`(frame,`[`AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__frame.html#ggae01fa7e427274293aacdf2adc17076bcaf50d0ed0a9a4517341c221be03a06c42)`)` for the motion vectors. The other two have no replacement. The documentation states that they're mpeg-specific and using internal implementation details, which is why no replacement was provided.

(Don't forget to set `avctx->`[`flags2`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#a1944f9a4f8f2e123c087e1fe7613d571) `&` [`AV_CODEC_FLAG2_EXPORT_MVS`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#ga33ff0b9183c222b2c509f34d1516969f), otherwise it's not exported.)

For the two with no replacement, I understand you might want that type of information if you're e.g. writing a stream analyzer, but FFmpeg really doesn't provide a stream-analyzer-level API right now. They could - if there's a more generic API - obviously be added as a separate side-data type. If you want that, you should probably become a FFmpeg developer and work on a broader API that is not MPEG-specific (e.g. does not use internal macros for mb_type), possibly even implement it for other codecs. In any other case, I don't really see why you would want that information. Can you elaborate?

Comment: hi, your guess was correct: i want to analyze a stream by comparing it to another stream. The two streams should come from two different devices, which means they are (supposed to be) encoded differently. Even though they are encoded using the same coding format (e.g H264 codec). I want to examine what exactly those differences are. I think motion vector and DCT Coefficient are two areas where those differences may reside. But unfortunately, and i don't quite understand why FFmpeg developers have made that piece of information deprecated...

Comment: I would recommend using a stream analyzer. I understand these things aren't always free, but neither is your time...

Comment: Then you'll unfortunately have to patch ffmpeg (or use an older version)... Again, I think they're happy to have this functionality, the API should just be much more generic, so with that changed, they'd probably accept a patch reintroducing this functionality (or reverting its removal).

Comment: Yes the only way I can think of right now to get those deprecated yet important attributes is to look into ffmpeg library and insert some printf methods at right places inside the library. But that will cost me very much effort...btw, in AVFrame->side_data struct, i did find motion_vector. Thank you